# Why form content is not filling in this picture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, adobe-after-effects, fill

In the next composition:

[image]

I don't know why fill is not working. Is an illustration imported from Illustrator and there object is showed properly, with shape color filled. But when I import in AfterEffects, whether using as a AI archive or converted form layers, the fill in this part of the guitar is like invisible.

What is happening?

Comment: One would need to examine the AI file to determine what's *special* about that shape or fill. It may be the fill is using a blending mode, or the shape itself is *not* a closed path.... This is impossible to answer without file examination, which is off-topic.